# Programatically getting the value of baseAddresses from seperate services in wcf config file

Tags: c#, wcf

Say I have the following wcf config file

```
<services>
  <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="Default" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" contract="CaptureService"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8501/service/service1.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="otherService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
    <endpoint address="start" behaviorConfiguration="Default" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" contract="CaptureService"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8501/service/service2.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

How can I cycle through the config to retrieve the values of the baseAdresses?
This is the method I want to do this in:

```
    public ServiceHost()
    {
        //read the config here

        this.service = svcType;
        this.scheme = new UriSchemeKeyedCollection(//list of values here);

        //add certain behaviours
        base.InitializeDescription(this.service, this.scheme);
        this.Description.Behaviors.Add(this);
    }
```

I feel like I may be going about this the complete wrong way though. Does anyone see anything inherently wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the configuration file, select the `system.serviceModel` section and go down to the `services` and their `host` elements and finally to their `baseAddresses`:

```
private static Uri[] GetBaseAddresses()
{
    // Get the application configuration file.
    // TODO: Might be adjusted for WCF hosted / web.config
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // Get the collection of the section groups.
    var sectionGroups = config.SectionGroups;

    // Get the serviceModel section
    var serviceModelSection = sectionGroups.OfType<ServiceModelSectionGroup>().SingleOrDefault();

    // Check if serviceModel section is configured
    if (serviceModelSection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Configuration section 'system.serviceModel' is missing.");

    // Get base addresses
    return (from ServiceElement service in serviceModelSection.Services.Services
            from BaseAddressElement baseAddress in service.Host.BaseAddresses
            select new Uri(baseAddress.BaseAddress)).ToArray();
}
```

Then simply consume the method in the constructor:

```
this.scheme = new UriSchemeKeyedCollection(GetBaseAddresses());
```